# Recursively find and enque latest mp3 files to audio player

Tags: unix, audio, find

I often add new mp3s into a deeply nested collection of folders. While I could re-add the whole collection to my audio player audacious I like to have the most recent additions at the end of the list.

How can I automatically find the latest songs in my collection and enque them to the existing list? 
Or how do I copy only the newest ones to my mp3 player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy latest 400 mp3 files into a folder:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.mp3' -printf '%T@ %c="%p"\n' | sort -k 1nr,1 -k 7 | cut -d'=' -f2- | head -n 400 |  xargs -I {} cp {} /media/mp3player
```

Enque latest 150 mp3s to Audacious, newest at end of list

```
find . -type f -iname '*.mp3' -printf '%T@ %c="%p"\n' | sort -k 1nr,1 -k 7 | cut -d'=' -f2- | head -n 150 | tac |  xargs -I {} audacious -e {}
```

Explained:

- find recursively files with extension mp3 in current folder (.)
- print the results with timestamp at beginning of line
- sort the lines (by the timestamp)
- cut off the timestamp
- take the first 150 lines
- reverse the lines (to have the latest song at the very end of your playlist)
- for each ask Audacious to enque it